# Replace one matched pattern with another in multiline text with sed

Tags: sed, sh, posix, portability

I have file with this text:

```
mirrors:
  docker.io:
    endpoint:
      - "http://registry:5000"
  registry:5000:
    endpoint:
      - "http://registry:5000"
  localhost:
    endpoint:
      - "http://registry:5000"
```

I need to replace it with this text in POSIX shell script (not bash):

```
mirrors:
  docker.io:
    endpoint:
      - "http://docker.io"
  registry:5000:
    endpoint:
      - "http://registry:5000"
  localhost:
    endpoint:
      - "http://localhost"
```

Replace should be done dynamically in all places without hard-coded names. I mean we should take sub-string from a first line ("docker.io", "registry:5000", "localhost") and replace with it sub-string "registry:5000" in a third line.

I've figure out regex, that splits it on 5 groups: `(^  )([^ ]*)(:[^"]*"http:\/\/)([^"]*)(")`

Then I've tried to use sed to print group 2 instead of 4, but this didn't work: `sed -n 's/\(^  \)\([^ ]*\)\(:[^"]*"http:\/\/\)\([^"]*\)\("\)/\1\2\3\2\5/p'`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1N;N;/\n.*endpoint:.*\n/s#((\S+):.*"http://)[^"]*#\1\2#;P;D' file
```

Open up a three line window into the file.

If the second line contains `endpoint:`, replace the last piece of text following `http://` with the first piece of text before `:`

Print/Delete the first line of the window and then replenish the three line window by appending the next line.

Repeat until the end of the file.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Awk would be a better candidate for this, passing in the string to change to as a variable str and the section to change (" docker.io" or " localhost" or " registry:5000") and so:

```
awk -v findstr=" docker.io" -v str="http://docker.io" '
$0 ~ findstr { dockfound=1 # We have found the section passed in findstr and so we set the dockfound marker
             } 
/endpoint/ && dockfound==1 { # We encounter endpoint after the dockfound marker is set and so we set the found marker
               found=1;
               print;
               next 
              } 
 found==1 && dockfound==1 { # We know from the found and the dockfound markers being set that we need to process this line
               match($0,/^[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]"/); # Match the start of the line to the beginning quote
               $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)str"\""; # Print the matched section followed by the replacement string (str) and the closing quote
               found=0; # Reset the markers
               dockfound=0 
               }1' file
```

One liner:

```
awk -v findstr=" docker.io" -v str="http://docker.io" '$0 ~ findstr { dockfound=1 } /endpoint/ && dockfound==1 { found=1;print;next } found==1 && dockfound==1 { match($0,/^[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]"/);$0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)str"\"";found=0;dockfound=0 }1' file
```

Comment: Not works because replace should be done dynamically in all places without hardcoded names.

Comment: I mean we should take sub-string from a first line ("docker.io", "registry:5000", "localhost") and replace with it sub-string "registry:5000" in a third line.

Comment: OK. I have amended the answer. It now needs the section to change as variable also.